# How to import xlwings functions in Excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlwings, vba

I installed the [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org) Python package using pip and subsequently installed the Excel add-in, using the steps documented [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html).

When I try to open an .xlsm file and then import the Python functions from an identically titled .py file, I get the following error message in Excel:
[image]

I tried reinstalling xlwings. I found no help specific to this error message online other than [this unanswered post](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/790).

[This github](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/blob/master/src/xlwingsdll/config.cpp) page code suggests this error message is thrown when

> a command is [not] specified in the config

I do not know what this means or how one would go about fixing it.

Python version: 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

xlwings version: 0.11.5-py36_0

Comment: what code are you using to load xlwings into your script and load the book with? You should include a snip of your code and the stack trace that the error gives you if you want us to help you.

Comment: No code. I have a .xlsm file and a .py file in the same folder. I am using the xlwings addin (toolbar) and trying to import the functions that are defined in the python code

Answer (score 0):

An xlwings reference needs to be added to the excel workbook.

From the xlwings Docs:

"Workbook preparation
The easiest way to start a new project is to run xlwings quickstart myproject on a command prompt (see Command Line Client (CLI)). This automatically adds the xlwings reference to the generated workbook."

Replace 'myproject' with the name for your workbook and it will auto generate the xlsm and py files.